# Emojis con API de Whatsapp Dart-Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Trato de enviar un mensaje con emojis pero aparecen con un rombo y un signo de interrogación en el �). Más o menos así está el contexto, pero ya intenté de todo sin lograr que se muestren los emojis en el mensaje, en el navegador se visualiza el link, ahí sí puedo ver mis emojis, pero cuando abre el chat y muestra el mensaje antes de abrir el chat, es cuando aparece el problema dentro del contenido.

```
String sms = "¡Hola! Soy ";
link = 'https://wa.me/+52$phone?text=$sms';
Uri _urlRed = Uri.parse(link);
await launchUrl(_urlRed,
        mode: LaunchMode.externalNonBrowserApplication)
```

Probe codificar el emoji, o alguna otra técnica que llegue ver en alguna página sin encontrar respuesta.

Comment: Tenés idea de cómo enviar emojis directamente con https://wa.me/number?text= En alguna de estos archivos https://github.com/techdirrdev/open_share_pro/tree/master/example puedo encontrar los códigos dependiendo del emoji que quiera utilizar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://pub.dev/packages/open_share_pro

use esa librería, probe con muchas y al final esa envió el mensaje correctamente con emojis, espero que a alguien más le sirva.

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución, revisar [answer].